# Android Studio folder for saving KML files?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I was wondering if there is a certain type of folder in Android Studio to insert KML files because there is no hint in the KML Importing Utility by Google Developers.
I tried it with the XML Resources folder because KML is some sort of XML in a way but with no success. I also checked the Raw Resources folder but that didnt work too.

I don´t really know how to implement a KML file to my Android project and i also need some help with understanding the code line.

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());

layer.addLayerToMap();
```

Mainly i don´t understand how to handle the "getMap" and the "getApplicationContext" passage.